# is there/what are the requirement(s) to use a specific release of rubygems with a specific release of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In particular, I have a rails 2.3.4 app which I am trying to upgrade to 2.3.16 to pick up some security fixes.  When I run 'script/about' after the rails upgrade I get

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:81:in
`add_load_paths': undefined method `requirement' for #
<Rails::GemDependency:0x7f408a59d040> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/initializer.rb:301:in
`add_gem_load_paths'
```

and I see that the 'def requirement' has in fact "disappeared" from gem_dependency between rails 2.3.4 and 2.3.16.

Googling doesn't give me a direct hit but some hits hint that there is some kind of dependency on rubygems.  The rubygems that my app is running with is 1.3.4.  What I'd really like to understand is if the rails core team has documented a matrix of specific rails to rubygems release dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is such a matrix, but I believe that if you use rubygems version 1.5.2 you will probably be okay.